# Characterization of convex space curve

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, curves-and-surfaces

In general, a smooth curve $C$ in $R^3$ that lies entirely on the boundary of its convex hull, $\mathcal{H}(C)$, is defined to be convex.

1. Does any one know of a characterization of a curve in space as convex depending on the sign of its torsion $\tau$?
2. Is the projection of a non-singular "short" curve in space to any plane always convex?

Where a "short" curve in space is such that there is a 1-1 correspondence between the space curve and the corresponding projected curve in a plane.

Thanks.

Comment: Any set $A$ lies entirely on its convex hull by definition: $A\subset CH(A)$. Or did I missunderstood something in your question?

Comment: I think it means "on the boundary of its convex hull".

Comment: Sorry about not being precise. I am referring to the definition of a convex curve as provided by Sedykh in http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01077070#page-1

Comment: I cannot make sense of the 2nd question. Perhaps this is what is meant: If some curve $C$ in space has the property that every projection of $C$ to a plane is simple, i.e., has no self-intersections, must then $C$ lie on its convex hull in 3D?

Comment: @Joseph: It seems to me that the second part says: *if all projections are simple, is it true that all projections are convex?*

Comment: For the 2nd question, I did mean what alvarezpaiva explains. I am not sure if the statement: if all projections of a space curve are convex then it lies on the boundary of it's convex hull is true.

Comment: In any case it is *impossible* that all projections be simple: join two points of the curve by a segment and project in the direction perpendicular to it. The most you can ask is that *almost all* projections be simple. I guess this only says the curve is planar.

Comment: @alvarezpaiva thanks for your comment, this answers by second question. I tried projecting a helix onto a few different planes and the result is always a non-convex planar curve.

Answer (score 2):

The first question is not tractable, as one can glean by reading [this paper by Bates and Melko](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.7086.pdf) (whence one learns that it took a century to produce a curve of *constant* torsion and non-vanishing curvature.) However, this paper has a lot of interesting stuff if you are interested in  this circle of questions.

Comment: That's an interesting reference! I like their CONJECTURE 3.3. *There are no closed curves of nonzero constant torsion on an ovaloid.*

Comment: Thanks for the link to the article. The notion of signed curvature for space curves seems interesting.